# How do I fix a shipping rule?

Tags: 7, commerce, rules

I have some rules to set the shipping rate depending on weight and address, but I can't make them work properly. The shipping rate is loaded, but there aren't changes with the weight.

```json
{
  "rules_atacama" : {
    "LABEL" : "Atacama",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [
      "rules",
      "commerce_physical",
      "commerce_order",
      "commerce_line_item",
      "commerce_shipping"
    ],
    "ON" : { "commerce_shipping_calculate_rate" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "commerce-line-item:type" ], "value" : "shipping" } },
      { "data_is" : {
          "data" : [ "commerce-line-item:commerce-shipping-service" ],
          "value" : "costos_envio"
        }
      },
      { "OR" : [
          { "commerce_physical_rules_order_weight_comparison" : {
              "commerce_order" : [ "commerce-line-item:order" ],
              "operator" : "\u003E=",
              "value" : "0",
              "unit" : "g"
            }
          },
          { "commerce_physical_rules_order_weight_comparison" : {
              "commerce_order" : [ "commerce-line-item:order" ],
              "operator" : "\u003C",
              "value" : "1500",
              "unit" : "g"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      { "entity_has_field" : {
          "entity" : [ "commerce-line-item:order" ],
          "field" : "commerce_customer_shipping"
        }
      },
      { "OR" : [
          { "commerce_order_compare_address" : {
              "commerce_order" : [ "commerce-line-item:order" ],
              "address_field" : "commerce_customer_shipping|commerce_customer_address",
              "address_component" : "administrative_area",
              "value" : "AT"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "commerce_line_item_unit_price_amount" : {
          "commerce_line_item" : [ "commerce_line_item" ],
          "amount" : "3350",
          "component_name" : "flat_rate_costos_envio",
          "round_mode" : "0"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're taking the pure rules route, you'll need a single rule per rate. So if you have two (2) zones and three (3) weight tiers, you'll need six (6) total rules. For example:

1. Northeast
2. Rest of the US

And

1. 0-5 lbs
2. 6-10 lbs
3. 11+ lbs

Will be 6 total rules:

1. Northeast (0-5 lbs)
2. Northeast (6-10 lbs)
3. Northeast (11+ lbs)
4. Rest of the US (0-5 lbs)
5. Rest of the US (6-10 lbs)
6. Rest of the US (11+ lbs)

You may also find it worth your time to review [Commerce Shipping Postal Code Weight](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_shipping_postal_code_weight) and [Commerce Shipping Weight Tariff](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_shipping_weight_tariff).

Comment: thanks! I prefer the rules, I have a lot of modules and am trying to not install more
I have one rule for each weight and province, but I have 2 problems: 1. If I choose any product always show me the same price for the same Province, no change when the weight is different, I have 4 rules, two for the same Province, one for 0 to 1500 grs and other to 1501 to 3000, the province selection works fine, just need to correctly set the weight. 2. I need a rule or loop that can take 2 or more products and make shipping by total weight of the order. Can you give some clues? thanks in advance